# VCL Button visual feeedback for touch screens and styling

Tags: c++, windows, vcl

I have a UI that is being used on a touch screen. The UI is using VCL styles.

Problem with this UI, when using the touch screen, is that regular TButtons stays "selected" after being pressed on by the finger. So pressing a button several times, give no visual feedback, making the user thinking that the button does not work.

Reading here: [Recognize touch as MouseDown event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23940143/recognize-touch-as-mousedown-event), it seems that one can override the WndProc function and do some manipulations in order to give better visual feedback when using touch. There also seem to be some bugs, regarding buttons and styles: [Default Button with VCL Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31975925/default-button-with-vcl-styles) that may play into the situation.

Question is, is overriding the WndProc function the way to go (?), and if so, which button class is most suitable for this, TButton, TBitBtn or TSpeedButton?

As I recall there is a big difference between TBitBtn and TSpeedButton in how they handle window messages but I'm not sure about this difference.

In addition to give proper visual feedback, I will need to add a button click sound, and perhaps that could be incorporated in the WndProc function as well?

Update: I found that using the VCL style, Sapphire Kamri is part of the problem. Using another style, like Luna, provide better (proper) visual feedback.

Comment: The link you posted solves a different issue altogether: Improving touch input by not relying on compatibility mouse messages and handling `WM_TOUCH` instead. Your issue is not related to this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable Which link are you referring to? In fact, the regular visual feedback given by using the mouse seem not to work with the particular style that I'm using, so it is not only related to touch usage.